# Grails: Clear errors when passing object to view

Tags: grails

I am checking if my user has entered the same password twice in controller:

```
if(params.password1 != "" || params.password2 != "") {
    // change password
    if(params.password1 != params.password2) {
        user.errors.rejectValue('password', 'noMatch')
    }

    user.password = params.password1
}

if (user.errors.errorCount > 0 || !user.save()) {

    println user.errors.errorCount
    render(view: "edituser", model: [userInstance: user])
    return
}
```

I get the correct user error count displayed in console so my if-clause works and Grails does not re-validate the object by using double pipe.

When I have a look into my GSP I get the following message:

> grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors

It seams like Grails clears all errors or uses an other object. It's curious, because my custom validator in my domain class works fine...

Comment: Any specific reason you aren't validating in your Domain class? Your validation rules should be in the Domain class and/or a Command object.  Then you'll be just testing for instance.hasErrors() without having to repeat the validation logic in your controller action.  If you're using validation in the domain as is suggested, then just test for errors with user.validate()

Comment: And what is the error count you are printing before rendering the gsp?